# How to set textarea focus in react-native webview

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I want to set textarea autoFoucs in react-native webview, but it doesn't work? somebody know how to slove it ? please contact me， thanks!

```
<WebView
ref={ref => this.webView = ref}
automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
style={{ width: this.mScreenWidth, flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: this._getSize(5), paddingHorizontal: this._getSize(16), paddingTop: this._getSize(5) }}
source={{ uri: 'http://localhost:8081/richEditor/richEditor.html' }}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
dataDetectorTypes='none'
startInLoadingState={true}
scrollEnabled={true} />

<textarea id="textarea" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> document.getElementById("textarea").focus(); </script>
```

Comment: 1. People should not contact you - this is a forum, and the way it works is that problems should be solved publicly, so others will benefit out of it as well.  2. You should post your code - what have you tried that does not work?

Comment: first of all , thanks for your advice. I edit the question again, please check it again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use autoFocus with input element

```
   <input autoFocus />
```